# Exterior points of the set $A = \lbrace (x, y) ∈ \Bbb R ^2 : y = sin(1/x), x\ne 0\rbrace$ of $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

I need to prove that all the points that are not in the line $y=sin(1/x)$ is an exterior point.

To do this, I need an explicit construction of the open ball which does not intersect with $A$ for all $(x_0,y_0)\in \Bbb R^2$.

The following is a construction:
From the continuity of $\sin(1/x)$. We choose $\epsilon > 0$
such that $|y_0 − \sin(1/x_0)| ≥ \epsilon$ .

Then there exist a $δ > 0$ such that
$0 \notin [x_0 − δ, x_0 + δ]$ and $|\sin(1/x) − \sin(1/x_0)| < \epsilon/2$ for every $x ∈ (x_0 − δ, x_0 + δ)$.

Take $r = \min\lbrace δ, \epsilon/2\rbrace$ we see that $\operatorname{Br}(x_0, y_0) ⊂ \Bbb R^2$
does not intersect the
graph of $y = \sin(1/x)$.

I cannot fully understand where do we use the continuity of the function. And why do we pick $\epsilon/2$ for the construction of $\delta$. Could someone please give some explanation? Thanks!

EDIT: Could someone please tell me how to see this by using definition of continuity of the $\sin(1/x)$? That is what I need. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Now my main problem is how to prove that the ball defined above does not intersect with the graph of $\sin(1/x)$. Could someone give a proof of that? Thanks!

Comment: The existance of $\delta$ follows from the continuity of $\sin$. We pick $\epsilon/2$ so it "works". I'm pretty sure that if you do all calculations it will popup somewhere and lead to the correct inequality that proves the statement.

Comment: @freakish Could you please tell me why it works? I think I really need a more explicit explaination from the definition of continuity.

Comment: We can also prove it the following way: $\sin(1/x)$ is a continuous function $ℝ \setminus \{0\} → ℝ$, so its graph is a closed subset of $ℝ \setminus \{0\} × ℝ$. Clearly, $ℝ × ((-∞, -1) ∪ (1, ∞))$ are also exterior points. On the other hand, the segment $\{0\} × [-1, 1]$ is the boundary of $A$.